# Regex: how to ignore nested brackets in [Y](X) pattern?

Tags: regex, brackets

I'm using Regular Expressions to find and replace parts of the text that look like this pattern:

```
[Y](X)
```

where X and Y are different phrases,
and the search process is based on X only

The following pattern does the job, but it replaces more text
when there are nested brackets

```
\[.*\]\(X\)
```

e.g.

```
[ZZZ [Y](X)
```

**Text Sample:**

> The [epidermis](Epidermis (skin)) (the outermost layer of skin) and the outer dermis (the layer beneath the epidermis).Contact dermatitis results in large, burning, and itchy rashes. These can take anywhere from several days to weeks to heal. This differentiates it from contact urticaria –

How can I fix my Regular Expression to avoid this?

Comment: The regex engine gives you the leftmost match that satisfies your expression. Since `.*` also matches square brackets, the match will start at the leftmost square bracket in the search text, which `.*` can connect to the the rest of your target string - how much of the search string that is, depends on whether the period may match line breaks. If you want to exclude those brackets, replace that sub-expression with a character class that does not allow square brackets, like `[^][]*`. That gives you `\[[^][]*\]\(your-search-term\)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you wanted to use a positive look ahead like:

In this sample:

> [epidermis](Epidermis (skin))

you do something like:

**`\[[^\[\]]*?\](?=\(Epidermis \(skin\)\))`**

Comment: Is this pattern [epidermis](Epidermis (skin)) what is expected output? epidermis?